# Switch statement not incrementing correctly

Tags: java, image, events, button

I have a button called `nextAd` that is supposed to show a different set of images each time it is clicked, but when I click it nothing comes up.

**Question: Why is my `switch` statement not causing different images to show up?**

***preferably without the use of an array***

```
  public class AdvertisementPanel extends JPanel {

        Advertisement apple = new Advertisement("Apple", new ImageIcon("./src/AppleAdvertisement.jpg"), new ImageIcon ("./src/AppleLogo.jpg"));
        Advertisement IBM = new Advertisement("IBM", new ImageIcon("./src/IBMAdvertisement.jpg"), new ImageIcon ("./src/IBMLogo.jpg"));
        Advertisement microsoft = new Advertisement("Microsoft", new ImageIcon("./src/MicrosoftAdvertisement.jpg"), new ImageIcon ("./src/MicrosoftLogo.jpg"));
        Advertisement samsung = new Advertisement("Samsung", new ImageIcon("./src/SamsungAdvertisement.jpg"), new ImageIcon ("./src/SamsungLogo.jpg"));

        JLabel appleTitle = new JLabel(apple.getTitle());
        JLabel IBMTitle = new JLabel(IBM.getTitle());
        JLabel microsoftTitle = new JLabel(microsoft.getTitle());
        JLabel samsungTitle = new JLabel(samsung.getTitle());

        JLabel appleAdPic = new JLabel(apple.getPicture1());
        JLabel IBMAdPic = new JLabel(IBM.getPicture1());
        JLabel microsoftAdPic = new JLabel(microsoft.getPicture1());
        JLabel samsungAdPic = new JLabel(samsung.getPicture1());

        JLabel appleLogo = new JLabel(apple.getPicture2());
        JLabel IBMLogo = new JLabel(IBM.getPicture2());
        JLabel microsoftLogo = new JLabel(microsoft.getPicture2());
        JLabel samsungLogo = new JLabel(samsung.getPicture2());

        JButton nextAd = new JButton("Click for the next advertisement");

        public AdvertisementPanel() 
        {

            //set up panel
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,1000));
            setBackground(Color.gray);

            //adds action listener to button
            nextAd.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

            //for Apple
            add(appleTitle);
            add(appleAdPic);
            add(appleLogo);

            //for IBM
            add(IBMTitle);
            add(IBMAdPic);
            add(IBMLogo);
            IBMTitle.setVisible(false);
            IBMAdPic.setVisible(false);
            IBMLogo.setVisible(false);

            //for Microsoft
            add(microsoftTitle);
            add(microsoftAdPic);
            add(microsoftLogo);
            microsoftTitle.setVisible(false);
            microsoftAdPic.setVisible(false);
            microsoftLogo.setVisible(false);

            //for Samsung
            add(samsungTitle);
            add(samsungAdPic);
            add(samsungLogo);
            samsungTitle.setVisible(false);
            samsungAdPic.setVisible(false);
            samsungLogo.setVisible(false);

            //for Button
            add(nextAd);

        private class buttonListener implements ActionListener

        {
            private int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            if(e.getSource() == nextAd);    
            {
                i++;    
            }
            switch (i){

            case '1': {
                appleTitle.setVisible(false);
                appleAdPic.setVisible(false);
                appleLogo.setVisible(false);
                IBMTitle.setVisible(true);
                IBMAdPic.setVisible(true);
                IBMLogo.setVisible(true);
                break;
            }
            case '2':{
                IBMAdPic.setVisible(false);
                IBMLogo.setVisible(false);
                microsoftAdPic.setVisible(true);
                microsoftLogo.setVisible(true);
                break;
            }
            case '3':{

                microsoftAdPic.setVisible(false);
                microsoftLogo.setVisible(false);
                samsungAdPic.setVisible(true);
                samsungLogo.setVisible(true);
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) ...

Comment: `./src/` won't exist after you build your program, so the images won't be found.  `ImageIcon(String)` expects a file resource, which you images are not...oh why am I bothering, you're obviously not listening since you've deleted your previous question on the same code...

Comment: No sorry, I was listening about the file location, however I was mainly concerned in figuring out why the switch statement wouldn't execute properly, which is what I've figured out here. I do appreciate you pointing that out and will make an effort to fix that as well.

Comment: Don't worry about me, I'm just having a crappy day, sorry for taking it out on you ;)

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `case '1':` You're comparing with a `char` (the literal ASCII character `1`), not a number. `1` is 49 in ASCII, so you're not really comparing with what you think you are.
2. The braces after `case foo:` are unnecessary. The `break` statement is actually breaking out of the blocks and not out of the `case`, so you should remove the `{}`s.
3. You set `private int = 0` *inside* the click listener, so it's always set to 0 and then incremented to 1, which does nothing. You need to declare it *outside* of the listener.

Comment: How can I make it register as "1 button click" then?

Comment: Uhh, what do you mean? Register what?

Comment: So if I click the button one time, it executes 'Case '1':' and if I click it a second time, it executues 'Case '2':', etc

Comment: That's exactly what it would do if you fixed the things mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Figured that part out, thank you. How then would I make it loop back at the original starting position where the 1st advertisement shows up and the sequence repeats?

Comment: If you changed `i++` to `i = (i + 1) % 3`, it would go 0-1-2-0-1-2-0-1-2-... (look up modulus operator). You would also have to change your `case`s to `0`, `1`, and `2`, and initialize `i` as `-1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have opening braces after the colons in your cases, don't need those, should be case 1 : stuff; break;

also make your int i a private instance variable, declared in your class rather than in the method, because everytime you click the button, the method runs, and i equals 0 again

example

```
switch (int) {
 case 1:
  stuff;
  moreStuff;
  break;
 case 2:
  stuff;
  moreStuff;
  break;
 case 3:
  stuff;
  moreStuff;
  break;
 default:
  default behavior;
  break;

}
```